# How to/best practice on how to differentiate between serialised objects stored within JSON format?

Tags: java, json, gson

Suppose that I serialise two different objects and save them to a directory.

Problem: Upon application start up, parsing the JSON files are not a problem - since GSON is employed, I can write my own serialisers and  deserialisers for both of the JSON files for their respective objects to be constructed.

But the problem is, how can I differentiate between the numerous JSON files in terms of what they store within them, so I can apply the correct deserialiser to it.

Thank you, best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider standardizing your JSON structure to include document type. You can even store the target object type in that field. Good practice is to include document version number as well. Example below shows two different versions of the 'account' document and a transaction document. All three can be stored in, say, the same Couchbase bucket. The way to differentiate between different documents would be to look at the "doc_type" field and the document version (if required). From the GSON serializer selection standpoint, you can look at at the "doc_type" in a switch/if-else statement or store the target object type in place of "account" or "transaction" and then, at the expense of performance, dynamically parse JSON to POJO.

```
{
  "doc_type": "account",
  "doc_ver": 1,
  "content": {
    "accnt_no": "12321645645484",
    "name": "Name or alias",
    "email": "Email address",
    "password": "Password in raw format",
    "exp_date": "06/10/2017"
  }
}


{
  "doc_type": "account",
  "doc_ver": 2,
  "content": {
    "accnt_no": "12321645645484",
    "name": "customer name",
    "email": "customer email",
    "password": "pass",
    "timezone": "customer timezone",
    "ip": "IP address",
    "spoken_languages": [ "EN", "RU" ],
    "exp_date": "06/10/2017"
  }
}

{
  "doc_type": "transaction",
  "doc_ver": 1,
  "content": {
    "accnt_no": "12321645645484",
    "tran_date": "06/04/2017",
    "tran_time":  "09:15:84.953"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean within the JSON file structure itself?

Comment: Dan, yes. See my edits above. Consider NoSQL database such as Couchbase. You should have 5 to 10 buckets to store your JSON documents, which means you'll end up with different types in the same collection/bucket. In your case a bucket becomes a directory. The key is to add "type" field to each document to be able to differentiate between them later.

Comment: One more thing - you don't need to have doc type and doc ver as part of your POJO if you don't want to. Just make sure to write that into a file on save so when you read it, you know which serializer to apply to the content field.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is parse JSON to a `HashMap<String, Object>` with multiple level. GSON will parse your JSON to `HashMap` with key is object name and value is an `object` (This object will belong to 3 type: `HashMap` for a object in JSON, `List` for an array in JSON and `String` for a string in JSON). To using this `HashMap` you need to iterate through the `HashMap` using a recursive method.